# AR apps with Android emulator

Tags: android, opengl-es, emulation, arcore

OpenGL ES version 3.1 is required (current minimum is 3.0) in Android emulator but system supports version 4.4.

I have to develop and `ARCore` app in Android for which the Android simulator should support the OpenGL ES version 3.1 or later, I checked on my system GPU is support the Open GL ver 4.4 but in Android emulator when I run my app it get crashed with message:

```
// OpenGL ES ver 3.1 minimum required (current is 3.0).
```

Please get me a way by which I can enable the Android emulator to use the latest Open GL ES version.

Comment: There is no "4.4" version of OpenGL **ES**. There is desktop OpenGL 4.4, but that's a different API.

Answer (score 0):

I believe requirement to have at least OpenGL ES Version 3.1 was changed relatively recently.  Following now mentions requirement for

> Development machine that supports OpenGL ES 3.0 or higher

https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/emulator

Also make sure you're using latest version of emulator (27.2.9 or later according to that page)

Comment: I have the Android emulator 27.3.10 and I could see that my system GPU support the OpenGL version 4.4 even though I am getting the error as OpenGL version 3.1 is minimum required (current is 3.0),
please do tell me what can I do to make my emulator run with the Latest OpenGL version